# Adding multiple texts to plot using matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How can I add multiple texts to a plot using the matplotlib.pyplot library. In the following code I manage to print the text but the NaN values are still displayed. Could it be done in some other way or omit these values. Attached is the image I obtain with the code.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import NearestNDInterpolator
from matplotlib import transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.linspace(np.nanmin(x), np.nanmax(x), 2500)
Y = np.linspace(np.nanmin(y), np.nanmax(y), 2500)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y, indexing='xy')
interp = NearestNDInterpolator(list(zip(x, y)), z)
Z = interp(X, Y)

figure = plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, shading='nearest')

# Properties
plt.axis('equal')
plt.axis('on')
plt.xlim(-Rx_Core, Rx_Core)
plt.ylim(-Rx_Core, Rx_Core)
plt.jet()
plt.clim(0.85, 1.25)

# Add text to plot

xtext = COORDXY_DATA[:, 1]
ytext = COORDXY_DATA[:, 0]

ztext = POWER_FULL_CORE

strmax = np.empty(ztext.shape)
for i in range(ztext.shape[0]):
    strmax[i] = np.array2string(ztext[i], precision=3)

for i in range(ztext.shape[0]):
    plt.text(xtext[i], ytext[i], strmax[i], 
             horizontalalignment='center',
             verticalalignment='center', fontsize=8)
# Save
plt.savefig('test.png', dpi=2500, transparent=True)
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance.[Image_Output.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0wRL.jpg)

Comment: Your code doesn't run so I can't test it, but I think that the simplest workaround would be to add the  condition `if strmax[i] != "nan":` just before the line where you call `plt.text`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm sorry but I couldn't add all the data that the code depends on. I agree with what you recommend but the problem is that the text is recognized NaN as a string, that's why it prints nan when it should not.

Comment: Try comparing it to np.nan then - I'm not sure what's the data type there

Comment: I already solved the problem using: `if np.isnan(strmax[i]) == False:` . Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the problem using: `if np.isnan(strmax[i]) == 0:` in the second for loop:

```
for i in range(ztext.shape[0]):
    if np.isnan(strmax[i]) == 0:
        plt.text(xtext[i], ytext[i], strmax[i], horizontalalignment='center',
                 verticalalignment='center', fontsize=8)
```